# Lexicographic Order Graphing

Tags: graphing-functions

How do I graph a lexicographic order?

A lexicographic function means $(a,b) ≤ (c,d)$ iff either

1) $a < c$

or

2) if $a=c$, then $b ≤ d$

So i want to graph the order determined by element $(c,d)$

What I've done so far is try to think of it through an example.
so i let $(c,d)$ = $(4,7)$
so the values that work for $(a,b)$ are if $a<3$, b can be any value and if $a=4$, $b≤7$.
Now I am not sure how to show this graphically.